# How to show/Hide/Collapse the sub report in a5w report based on true/false column in the table?

Tags: report

I have report with some sub-report in it. Can I show/Hide the sub report based on the content in the table. For example, I have a column name "has_header" set to false and in that case I do not want the header-sub-report to display on the report.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!! I went too complicated before trying the basic. In sub-report>> specify the filter: in my case I put `Has_header=.T.` and things is done. I am not sure if this is the exact solution but, it fixes my problem.